# using versions in Jenkins Pipeline shared libraries

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am storing my Jenkins Pipeline as groovy scripts inside the shared libraries in Jenkins. I want to use different versions for different jobs. My shared Library script called as `sample_jenkins.groovy` is as follows:

```groovy
def call(body) {
  // evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
  def config = [:]
  body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  body.delegate = config
  body()

  // now build, based on the configuration provided
  node {
    stage ('First Stage'){
      echo "This is first stage"
    }
    stage('Second Stage'){
      echo "This is second stage"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tagged the different versions in my sharedLib repo as `v1.0` and `v2.0`. Incase I want to use `v1.0`, I have referenced to it as follows with `@Library` annotation as follows.

From my job, I have accessed the shared Library by calling the groovy script and used the annotation `@Library('project-examples@v1.0')` above it, like in this picture:

[image: pipeline script consuming version <code>v1.0</code> with <code>@Library</code>]

I am getting errors when I run the job. 
Here are the errors I am seeing.

[image: pipeline script error messages]

I get the same error when I use `@Library('project-examples@master')`. Am I going wrong somewhere? How are we supposed to use versioning if this is not the case? How do I tell Jenkins which version to use? Can someone give me a clear picture of how to make use of versions in jenkins shared library?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to execute this"?  What exactly happens?  Have you verified that just "master" gets you at least the library on the HEAD of master?

Comment: I am getting errors when I run the job. Yes I tried with master too and got the same errors.

Comment: This is the error I am getting:WorkflowScript: 2: unexpected token: my_jenkinsfile @ line 2, column 1.
  my_jenkinsfile{
   ^

1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)

Comment: Please post a more complete version of what you're trying to do, including your shared library, and complete error diagnostics. This clearly has nothing to do with shared library versions.

Comment: I have edited the post with more details.

Comment: What directory in the shared library did you put this file?  It needs to be in "vars".

Comment: Yes it is vars.

Comment: It works fine without the @Library annotation. But I want to make use of versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I remember what the problem very likely is. Groovy annotations have to annotate "something".  It's handy if you have an import statement, as `@Library` can go on that, even if they have no real relation. If you don't have an import statement, then you have to do something that looks really odd. You have to have it annotate "_".

Review https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ again for an example of this.